# Extract names from SQLite table and return the distinct count with the corresponding name

Tags: sqlite

I need help extracting the names of animal from a SQLite "animal" table and return the name of the animal and the number of occurrence. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Animal,12,5) 
FROM  LOG 
where Animal LIKE "%This is a%"**
```

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNGkr.png)

Answer (score 1):

If the prefix `'This is a '` is the same in all values of the column `Animal`:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Animal, 11) AS Animal, 
       COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM LOG 
GROUP BY Animal
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=fbfc4bba2d4137bafd36e7504d62fb8e).